# Как выровнять иконки по центру блока bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

center-block и text-center не работает.
Нужно разместить иконки по центру:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="social twitter">
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x center-block"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="social instagram">
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="social facebook">
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>    
    </div>
    <div class="social vk">
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-vk fa-2x"></i></a>    
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);
.social a{
    text-align:center;
    width:46px;
    height:46px;
    float:left;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15), inset 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-radius:46px;
    margin:0 10px 10px 0;
    padding:6px;
    color:#000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавь с css

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-1 flex-center">
            <div class="social twitter">
                <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x center-block"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="social instagram">
                <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="social facebook">
                <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>    
            </div>
           <div class="social vk">
                <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-vk fa-2x"></i></a>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);
.social a{
    text-align:center;
    width:46px;
    height:46px;
    float:left;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15), inset 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-radius:46px;
    margin:0 10px 10px 0;
    padding:6px;
    color:#000;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.flex-center{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
<style>
```

Comment: не работает нужно чтобы они были в один ряд, а если прописать inline-flex, то они становятся слева, как исправить?

Comment: м.б. не так скопировал? https://jsfiddle.net/19nptusj/5/ - все ровно

Comment: мне нужно по центру страницы, а они просто слева

Comment: надо было сразу так и говорить - https://jsfiddle.net/49awptg1 . Рекомендую ознакомится с flex -https://habr.com/post/313938/

Comment: спасибо работает, я нашел ещё один метод может он и кривоват но работает, через col-md-4

Answer (score 1):

```css
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);
.social a{
    text-align:center;
    width:46px;
    height:46px;
    float:left;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15), inset 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-radius:46px;
    margin:0 10px 10px 0;
    padding:6px;
    color:#000;
    display: flex;
    text-decoration: none;
    justify-content: center;
}

.social i {align-self: center;}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="social twitter">
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x center-block"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="social instagram">
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="social facebook">
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>    
    </div>
    <div class="social vk">
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-vk fa-2x"></i></a>    
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Попробуйте так флексом

Comment: они становятся в столбик

Comment: Вы нажали выполнить код кнопку? Всё там нормально.

Comment: мне нужно выравнять по центру страницы, а они слева, подскажите как их поставить по центру?